# One CSS class with jQuery Click Function Exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
.box {
    width:45px;
    height:45px;
    line-height:45px;
    border:1px solid #808080;
    border-radius:8px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#000;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:24px; 
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    cursor:context-menu;
}
```

I have a CSS class called .box and have a php loop where I am creating div layers referring to the class like this:

```
<div class="box">content</div>
```

I then have a jQuery click function that listens for clicks on the div layer with `class="box"` like this:

```
$(".box").click(function(){
```

my question is that within my loop there will be certain div layers that still need to be styled like the `.box` class but I do not want the click function to apply to. The way I have solved it currently is creating a clone of `.box` and calling it `.box2` and seeing as there is not `.box2` click event then only the jQuery click function applies to the `.box` class div.

However, I am wondering if there is a better way to do it and just stick to one class rather than two, as this is extra code and everytime I want to change style, I have to replicate it twice. Is there maybe a way to add some extra parameters and make it something like `class="box active"` ?

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: i suggest you take a look at jquery selectors http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: You need to make your selector more specific. Either with data attributes, other class names, the element its applied to. You could scope it to a button or anchor element for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `active` like:-

```
$(".box.active").click(function(){
```

This will bind the click event to elements which has both classes (`class="box active"`).